# In calibration plot using R, how to add the distribution of probability using needle below and above a line?

Tags: r, prediction, calibration

In this calibration plot of prediction model, the distribution of probability groupped by binary outcome was plotted using needles, how to realize it based on basic R plot function?

[image]

Can any R progrommer present an example code?

Comment: Could you edit your question to make it reproducible and add some code? With Stack Overflow question, the burden is on **you** (the asker) to present some example code, not the community trying to help. As it stands, this question make it very difficult to provide any insight. Some tips on how to ask a good reproducible R question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Good luck!

Comment: @YellowBridge Just searching about "calibration curves in R" results to many tutorials or packages regarding them so you should just put a little effort in.

Comment: Thanks for your warming reminder. I have searched online, and find `val.prob` and `calibrate` in rms package, `calibration_plot` in predtools package, and `calPlot` in the calPlot package to make a calibration plot.

Comment: @YellowBridge That's very good. And you seem to be aware on unpacking the functions as well from the packages so this issue is likely just a breeze.

Answer (score 2):

There is tons of packages out there already regarding calibration curves. Most are built around `rms` so it is quite easy to find one that suites your needs. `rms` itself already has `val.prob()` for calibration curves. Here is an example from `CalibrationCurves` package which loads `rms`.

```
# Load package
library(CalibrationCurves)
set.seed(1783)

# Simulate training data
X      = replicate(4, rnorm(5e2))
p0true = binomial()$linkinv(cbind(1, X) %*% c(0.1, 0.5, 1.2, -0.75, 0.8))
y      = rbinom(5e2, 1, p0true)
Df     = data.frame(y, X)

# Fit logistic model
FitLog = lrm(y ~ ., Df)

# Simulate validation data
Xval   = replicate(4, rnorm(5e2))
p0true = binomial()$linkinv(cbind(1, Xval) %*% c(0.1, 0.5, 1.2, -0.75, 0.8))
yval   = rbinom(5e2, 1, p0true)
Pred   = binomial()$linkinv(cbind(1, Xval) %*% coef(FitLog))

# Default calibration plot
valProbggplot(Pred, yval)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your great solution. After look into the valProbggplot function, it is a ggplot solution. In lines 450-463, two geom_segment are used to draw the needle above and below a horizontal line and a geom_line is used to draw the line.  Based on these codes, further modification can be made. Thanks again.